# How to copy HTML tags automatically using PHP

Tags: php, html

I was wondering if there was a way to copy the html tags in php like

```
<tag1><tag2>  text...............text...........</tag2></tag1>
```

Now I am one html pages into several depending on the character count so if the text is long then it will get split in the middle but the tags will not be copied.

So I wanted a way to close the tags automatically at the end of the page and start a new tag at the start of the next page in php.

Thanxx for helping me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

split the html, then repair with

http://www.php.net/tidy

or, much easier I guess,

http://www.php.net/domdocument

using the method ->loadHTML() ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php )

HTH

edit: code example

```
<?php
function getBodyContent(DOMDocument $doc)
{
    $b = $doc->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0); $bx = "";
    for($x=0;$x<$b->childNodes->length;$x++)
    $bx .= $doc->saveHTML($b->childNodes->item($x));
    return $bx;
}

header("Content-Type: text/plain");

$string="<h1><b>hello dfasadf safsa</b> sdf <i>sadf</i></h1> <p> sdfs dfsdfsdf</p>";

$a = new DOMDocument(); @$a->loadHTML(mb_substr($string, 0, 10, "UTF-8"));
echo getBodyContent($a); echo "\n\n\n";

$a = new DOMDocument(); @$a->loadHTML(mb_substr($string, 10, 1000, "UTF-8"));
echo getBodyContent($a); echo "\n\n\n";

$a = new DOMDocument(); @$a->loadHTML(mb_substr($string, 0, 40, "UTF-8"));
echo getBodyContent($a); echo "\n\n\n";

$a = new DOMDocument(); @$a->loadHTML(mb_substr($string, 40, 1000, "UTF-8"));
echo getBodyContent($a); echo "\n\n\n";

?>
```

Comment: hey Thanx Wes I am looking into it now. I was wondering if I could save the description of the tag in to a variable i.e. whatever is between the <> brackets store it and then close it at the end. If it is possible then what php commands can be used?

Comment: The input I will get is via a rich text editor and stored in the mysql table and so it will have a variety off tags ranging from colour to size.

Comment: ok ummm I am trying to get the tag description into a variable like say <body> is the tag then I want $var=body. I am taking the input into my table via a rich text editor and so a tag can contain many things like colour language font size etc. and I want the full thing in a variable eg <span lang="AR-EG" style="font-size: 22pt; font-family: &quot;Simplified Arabic&quot;; color: blue;"> then $var =span lang="AR-EG" style="font-size: 22pt; font-family: &quot;Simplified Arabic&quot;; color: blue;"

Comment: once I have the tag description in a variable then I can actually close it and add it at the end of a page and then open the same one on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Thing is there can be different solution based on what your data is?

can you separate your data into like how many words/characters per page?

- if you can then it makes things easy as there are loads of scripts you can use - easy and simple ones to advanced one.

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm yeah I can split the data based on the number of characters. Like once the data is fetched I split the data by keeping a 500 character limit and convert each set of data into a new html page. Now the problem was closing tags at the end and adding new ones at the begining of a new page

Comment: Hi Dhaval Sorry for late reply - if that is the case there are lots of script available on goole... find for pagination using jquery, ajax, php...  if you do not want to use ajax - then as you said you can split all into set of characters.... split them - put into array... get the array index as page number and show array index of whichever page number selected...   if you want to put tags only then once you have array use "<tag>".array[$pageno]."</tag>";